# run executable jar files and run another task with Kotlin DSL's task

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to run the tasks with a specific name and run executable jar files with Kotlin DSL's task but I can't find how in hours, and also I don't know if it is possible.

help me please ;-;

here is my code

```
tasks {
    shadowJar {
        destinationDirectory.set(file("TestBukkit/plugins/"))
    }

    val runTestBukkit by registering {
        doFirst {
            //want to run a task named "shadowJar"
        }
        doLast {
            //want to run executable jar with flags
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically three ways of chaining tasks in Gradle.

For you, the TL;DR is probably

```kotlin
val runTestBukkit by tasks.registering(JavaExec::class) {
  dependsOn(tasks.shadowJar)
  // to run an executable jar with flags, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html
}
```

See the documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html for more details

#### `doLast { ... }` & `doFirst { ... }` - Adding actions to an existing task

Docs: [Manipulating existing tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:manipulating_existing_tasks)

You can amend an existing task to perform additional actions before or after its execution...

```kotlin
tasks.shadowJar {
  doFirst {
    logger.lifecycle("I'm an extra action!")
  }
  doLast {
    copy {
      from(this@shadowJar.outputs)
      into(project.buildDirectory.dir("copied-shadow-jar"))
    }
  }
}
```

These additional actions will be performed whenever `tasks.shadowJar` runs. They are executed in the order they are defined in the code.

This can be really handy for adding small additional tasks, like cleaning up directories, or copying task outputs. More complicated tasks can be a bit more tricky though, so for that it's best to use `dependsOn(...)`...

#### `dependsOn(...)` Adding task dependencies

Docs: [Adding dependencies to a task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks)

Sometimes you want tasks that depend on other tasks running successfully. Maybe because they need to succeed, or because they produce an artifact that you want to consume.

You can also create a new task that either depends on other tasks...

```kotlin
val runTestBukkit by tasks.registering {
  dependsOn(tasks.shadowJar) 
}
```

Using `dependsOn` means `shadowJar` *must* run successfully before `runTestBukkit` runs, but `runTestBukkit` won't run unless it is specifically requested
(either with `./gradlew :runTestBukkit`, or if another task depends on it). If `shadowJar` fails, then `runTestBukkit` won't run.

`dependsOn` can be *really* handy if the `shadowJar` produces an artifact, and Gradle caches the input and output. No matter how many times you run `runTestBukkit`, `shadowJar` will only run if necessary!

#### `finalizedBy(...)`

Docs: [Finalizer tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks)

Sometimes you *always* want a task to run after another task. For that you can use `finalizedBy(...)`. You'll often see it when it comes to test report generation - For example, I  *always* want the test report to be generated, even if the `test` task fails.

```kotlin
tasks.test {
  finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport)
}
```

Comment: thank you for letting me know easily and thank you for your time!!
it was very helpful. appreciate to you